# How do I create an Android Library inside a non-Android Gradle project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I'm trying to create a library that reuses some of my existing (plain Java) code. The library was working fine on its own but when I moved it into the bigger project I ran into some issues:

- Android studio now "opens" the super-project instead of the Android one
- Android studio no longer recognizes Android files properly, they just get tagged as "Java Classes" with the circle-C icon
- My demo application is no longer executable either

How can this be set up so that android studio doesn't really show the super project?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can upload your library to github and add it as dependency of your bigger project like :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.yourSampleLib:yourVersion'   
}
```